# Drupal and Hiphop php VM

Tags: 7

Faceboock has just released on GitHub their new Hiphop PHP VM, please follow this link:

- https://github.com/Facebook/hiphop-php/wiki

Do you know if it is possible to enhance Drupal performance with HipHop PHP VM?

If yes, do you have a good howto, or the different steps to make it work, with a CDN?

Comment: By the way, I tried to create the tag Hiphop, but I don't have enough points at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the time of writing Drupal does not work out-of-the-box with HipHop VM (1). Some people have managed to make it work with previous versions, but there isn't a simple easy option.

On php.webtutor.pl you can find a number of useful resources:

- [A benchmark of Drupal comparing standalone PHP, PHP with APC, and HipHop](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/17/drupal-hiphop-for-php-vs-apc-benchmark/) ;
- [The patch that was used to make Drupal run under Hiphop](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/31/drupal-hh7-project-hiphop-for-php-and-drupal-7-2-compatibility-patch/)

These are for an older version of Drupal 7 (7.2) and an older version of Hiphop. However the patches are still useful as a place to start. Some of the issues addressed in the patches (eg. the infinite loop caused by drupal autoload) are still current - others may or may not be, I have not investigated further myself though [the article by @tvlooy suggests the PDO issues have been fixed](http://blog.ctors.net/home/playingwithhiphopvm).

The article at http://nickveenhof.be/blog/getting-drupal-7-almost-running-hhvm (on which the tests by @tvlooy was based) provides an example configuration - even though the author failed to get Drupal to run under HHVM, it gives a helpful starting point in addition to the webtutor patches.

(1) As tested with Drupal 7.22 and the latest development version of HipHop (HEAD on the master branch) as of 01/08/2013

**Edit:** [A post made on the 12/09/13](http://www.hhvm.com/blog/875/wow-hhvm-is-fast-too-bad-it-doesnt-run-my-code) (after this answer was written) on the HHVM blog suggests that HHVM now passes 98% of Drupal core unit tests. There has been more HHVM releases since then - [a comment on the 2.2.0 release](http://www.hhvm.com/blog/1301/hhvm-2-2-0#comment-5795) that came out a month later suggests that Drupal 7 can be installed using HHVM, though file uploading, clean URLs and php-gd do not work. I do not want to change my original answer as I have not tested this myself, however the comment (together with the 2.2.0 changelog) suggests that some of the issues, such as the autoload loop, have been fixed.

Comment: Considering that this is about as much info as is available on the subject, your answer is good. However most of it, other than the configuration, deals with an old version of hiphop that is deprecated, so it's not terribly useful.\

Comment: While it concerns an older version of Hiphop some of the issues fixed in the patch provided by webtutor are still there in the current version (eg. the inifinte loop caused by drupal autoload). The information given here does not, as mentioned in the answer, give an out of the box solution. But it gives helpful pointers about where to start if you want to try HHVM with Drupal yourself.

Comment: And I should add that the fact that HHVM does not work with Drupal is true with the current versions of HHVM and Drupal ; this is not deprecated information.

Comment: Cool, you should add the above info to the question.

Comment: @Letharion: done :)

Comment: @AliceHeaton thanks for this review. So at the moment, I can consider that this is not working. Right ?

Comment: @ttoine : it is not working as-is ; but it could be made to work with some time and effort.

Comment: This blog post (from 2013-12-19) suggest that 100% of Drupal's tests pass with latest dev version of HHVM:

http://www.hhvm.com/blog/2813/we-are-the-98-5-and-the-16

I haven't personally tested it, but after reading I started looking for people who have and found my way here. :-)